# pandas group by year, id and do some statistics per id? with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that is the child of a merge operation on two dataframes. I end up with a multi-index that looks like (timestamp,id) and for the sake of argument, a single column X.

I would like to do several statistics on X by year, and by ID. Instead of posting all the crazy errors that I am getting trying to blindly solve this problem, I ask instead "how would you do this?"

There is one row of X per id, per period (daily). I want to aggregate to an annual period.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) and aggregate e.g. `sum`, but need [pandas 0.18.1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-syntax-with-window-and-resample-operations):

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2016-12-28')
rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': rng, 'X': range(10), 
                   'id': ['a'] * 3 + ['b'] * 3 + ['c'] * 4 })  
df = df.set_index(['timestamp','id'])
print (df)
               X
timestamp  id   
2016-12-28 a   0
2016-12-29 a   1
2016-12-30 a   2
2016-12-31 b   3
2017-01-01 b   4
2017-01-02 b   5
2017-01-03 c   6
2017-01-04 c   7
2017-01-05 c   8
2017-01-06 c   9

df = df.reset_index(level='id')
print (df.groupby('id').resample('A')['X'].sum())
id  timestamp 
a   2016-12-31     3
b   2016-12-31     3
    2017-12-31     9
c   2017-12-31    30
Name: X, dtype: int32
```

Another solution is use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with `groupby`:

```
print (df.X.groupby([df.index.get_level_values('timestamp').year,
                     df.index.get_level_values('id')])
           .sum())
      id
2016  a      3
      b      3
2017  b      9
      c     30
Name: X, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that the groups happen together then you must place all the groups in the groupby.

Assuming your timestamp is in the left outer group, the following should work.

```
df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('A', level=0), pd.Grouper(level='id')])['X'].sum()
```

Comment: I think this is what I want. Since I asked my question I arrived at something very similar: grp_period_id = df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('A'), 'ID'])

Comment: OK cool. If you are using 'ID' on its own then it must be a column and not in the index.

Comment: i will say that the road to this simple solution was littered with very cryptic error messages and what seems like pretty light documentation. pandas giveth productivity on the front end (e.g. merge) and pandas taketh away on the backend (e.g. "why can't I X")